# Regularity of Gauss Manin connection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

I want to understand the "Regularity of Gauss Manin connection" from the most basic example.
Suppose we have a family of projective manifold $X\rightarrow \mathbb C^*$ with full rank, then for any kth cohomology group, we have holomorphic bundle $H_{\mathbb C}$ with filtration $F^p$ coupled with the Gauss Manin connection
$$\nabla: F^P\rightarrow F^{p-1}\otimes\Omega^1.$$
I have a some couple of questions here.

1 I saw one definition of Regularity in Griffiths's paper, which means in terms of a local rational basis of $H_{\mathbb C}$ (holomorphic on $\mathbb C^*$), the connection form has poles at the origion.

I feel confused about the existence of rational sections which can form a basis of $H_{\mathbb C}$. Why they exists.
Also I little bit confused about the terminology "rational". Since it is required to be holomorphic outside the origion, why not just call it holomorphic section.

2 Is there any concrete example computed to see this regularity in this context. Reference will be helpful.

Comment: If you can read french, Deligne's "Equations différentielles à points singuliers réguliers" (LNM 163) is certainly the best reference.

Comment: There is also a translation available at https://labs.thosgood.com/translations/978-3-540-05190-9.pdf

Comment: @abx@pbelmans  Thanks. The translation will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$H_{\mathbb C}$ is a holomorphic vector bundle over a punctured disk, so it is trivial since every holomorphic vector bundle over $\mathbb C^*$ is trivial, hence, there exist global holomorphic sections $\eta_1,...,\eta_r$ over $\mathbb C^*$ which are trivialization of $H_{\mathbb C}$.

I guess "rational" here because construction of $H_{\mathbb C}$ is purely algebraic (it is analytification of algebraic vector bundle associated with locally free sheaf $R^k f_* \mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb C} \mathcal O_{\mathbb C^*}$), hence $\eta_i$ could be chosen from algebraic sections of $H_{\mathbb C}$ over $\mathbb C^*$ which are rational sections over $\mathbb C$, but more context is required to say for sure.

You can take a look on pp5-6 of [Brian Conrad "CLASSICAL MOTIVATION FOR THE RIEMANN–HILBERT
CORRESPONDENCE"](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/rhtalk.pdf)

Comment: @Pochekai Thanks. I realize that the holomorphic vector bundle over the punctured disk is trivial, which is intuitively true to me. But for higher dimensional base (punctured polydisk),  I think nontrivial holomorphic bundle exists. Then such a definition confuse me. Here is more context in case you are interested. pp 10 https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/periodsofintegral.pdf

Comment: @xinfu This is a part of the definition, not a statement. "We say $D$ have regular singular points on infinity if for any compactification $\overline{S}$, for any point $\overline{s} \in \overline{S} - S$  there exist topological neighborhood $U$ of $\overline{s}$ and raitonal sections $\eta_1,...,\eta_r$ of $E$ over $S$ which are holomorphic basis of $E$ over $U \cap S$ such that..." Thus, if vector bundle $E$ is not holomorphically trivializable near some point $\overline{s} \in \overline{S} - S$ (which could be the case) then $D$ is not a connection with regular singular points on infinity.